# Unable to create Generic CustomAttributeData properly when using programatically generated Enum

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums, custom-attributes

I am trying to source a PropertyGrid with a dynamically generated object.

For combo selections on this property grid, I have built a TypeConverter (where T is an enum, defining the list of options):

```
    public class TypedConverter<T> : StringConverter where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        ...

        public override System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection
            GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");            

            string[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();

            return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
        }

    }
```

I can then add a custom attribute to the property, referencing this TypeConverter, as below (typedConverterGenericType is the the type of TypedConverter with an enum generic argument)

```
CustomAttributeBuilder attributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(TypeConverterAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Type) }), new Type[] { typedConverterGenericType });

propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);
```

This works **great**, as long as the Enum in question is hardcoded: `AddTypeConverterAttribute(propertyBuilder, typeof(TypedConverter<Fred>));`. In the debugger, the attribute on the property gives me `{[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute( ...`.

However, when I use a dynamically built enum (that I have determined is generated properly in reflection) does not work:

```
   Type enumType = enumBuilder.CreateType();//This generates a proper enum, as I have determined in reflection

   Type converterType = typeof(TypedConverter<>);

   Type typedConverterType = converterType.MakeGenericType(enumType);

   AddTypeConverterAttribute(propertyBuilder, typedConverterType);
```

In the debugger, the attribute on the property now gives me `{System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData}`, and drilling into this, I have an error on the ConstructorArguments `... Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData>(type.GetProperties()[1].CustomAttributes).Items[4].ConstructorArguments' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'`

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the TypeConverter attribute set properly?

**EDIT**: In case someone wants to see how I add the attribute

```
private void AddTypeConverterAttribute(PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, Type typedConverterGenericType)
{
   CustomAttributeBuilder attributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(TypeConverterAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Type) }), new Type[] { typedConverterGenericType });

   propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);        
}
```

**EDIT2**

Testing confirms it is an issue with the dynamically built enum - if I create the generic type with `Type typedConverterType = converterType.MakeGenericType(typeof(Fred));` it works fine.

**EDIT 3**

My test project is available [here](http://purehumbug.com/files/PropertiesExample.zip). It is reading some JSON from Resouces, and trying to generate a class whose type is described by that JSON.

I am creating an instance of that class (`Activator.CreateInstance`) that will source a PropertyGrid. To get combo selection on that PropertyGrid, I am creating a Type, with a property attributed with TypedConverter, where T is an enum that describes the values in the combo selection.

This works great for hardcoded enums, but not for programatically generated ones

Comment: Have you tried `public EnumBuilder DefineEnum(string name, TypeAttributes visibility, Type underlyingType);` in ` System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder`? Here's, an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mrtig Yes, I didn't include it for brevity's sake. `EnumBuilder builder = moduleBuilder.DefineEnum(name, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));` is how I get my enumBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that there is a simple solution to this problem. You need to set the AssemblyResolve event of your current domain and return the the requested assembly in the event handler:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{

    return AppDomain
               .CurrentDomain
               .GetAssemblies()
               .FirstOrDefault(assembly => assembly.FullName == args.Name);
}
```

This will make your dynamically generated Enums work

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to get this working by using different dynamic assemblies. Let me know if this works for you:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
AssemblyName enumAssembly = new AssemblyName("enumAssembly");

AssemblyBuilder ab = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    enumAssembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(enumAssembly.Name, 
    enumAssembly.Name + ".dll");

// Define a public enumeration with the name "Foo" and an 
// underlying type of Integer.
EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("Foo", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

eb.DefineLiteral("Bar", 0);
eb.DefineLiteral("Baz", 1);

Type final_foo = eb.CreateType();

ab.Save(enumAssembly.Name + ".dll");
var converterType = typeof(TypedConverter<>);

AssemblyName dynamicAsm = new AssemblyName();
dynamicAsm.Name = "DynamicAsm";

// To generate a persistable assembly, specify AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave.
AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAsm,
                                                AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
// Generate a persistable single-module assembly.
ModuleBuilder myModBuilder =
    myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(dynamicAsm.Name, dynamicAsm.Name + ".dll");

TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder = myModBuilder.DefineType("CustomerData",
                                                TypeAttributes.Public);

PropertyBuilder custNamePropBldr = myTypeBuilder.DefineProperty("elevation",
                                                PropertyAttributes.HasDefault,
                                                final_foo,
                                                null);


var typedConverterType = converterType.MakeGenericType(final_foo);

CustomAttributeBuilder attributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(
    typeof(TypeConverterAttribute).GetConstructor(
        new Type[] { typeof(Type) }), 
        new Type[] { typedConverterType }
    );

custNamePropBldr.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at that, on train on the way home now on a Friday arvo. Promise I'll check this out ASAP and let you know

Comment: Sorry, dude, tried different assemblies, same assemblies, RunAndSave, just Run, just Save, Saved and not saved dlls. Funny thing, though, my saved dlls appear empty according to dotpeek,

Comment: So, is what you're trying to do materially different from the example I used?

Comment: Not really, but we both appear to have the same issue. What I am trying to do is create a type that has a property with a TypeConverter attribute that is successfully reflected on by the WinForms PropertyGrid, so I can programatically set combo box options for that value. My problem is that, whilst this works for a hardcoded enum, the dynamically generated enum I built is not reflected on properly by the PropertyGrid. I will update the question to better describe this, and include a source download